# Multiple warnings in .net when running code analysis

Tags: .net, pinvoke

I am running code analysis in VS and there are around 130 warnings from 2 different p/invoke's that are pretty much all the same.  It tells me to marshal a field (that I do not have anywhere in my project) as unicode, which normally I could probably figure out.  The problem is, I do not have any of these 65 fields anywhere in my project.

```
<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetlastError:=True)> _
Friend Shared Function WriteFile(ByVal hFile As IntPtr, ByVal Buffer As Byte(),
ByVal nNumberOfBytesToWrite As Integer, ByRef lpNumberOfBytesWritten As Integer,
ByVal lpOverlapped As Overlapped) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
End Function

<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetlastError:=True)> _
Friend Shared Function ReadFile(ByVal hFile As IntPtr, ByVal Buffer As Byte(), _
ByVal nNumberOfBytesToRead As Integer, ByRef lpNumberOfBytesRead As Integer, _
ByVal lpOverlapped As System.Threading.Overlapped) As Integer
End Function
```

Here is an example of the warnings I am receiving.

CA2101 : Microsoft.Globalization : To reduce security risk, marshal field 'ActivationArguments.m_appFullName' as Unicode, by setting StructLayout.CharSet on 'ActivationArguments' to CharSet.Unicode, or by explicitly marshaling the field as UnmanagedType.LPWStr. If you need to marshal this string as ANSI or system-dependent, specify MarshalAs explicitly, use the BestFitMapping attribute to turn best-fit mapping off, and for added security, to turn ThrowOnUnmappableChar on.

Comment: Why are you using overlapped? Are you doing overlapped IO? If not use ByVal IntPtr and pass IntPtr.Zero.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for replying.  I ended up looking up the code on pinvoke.net and changed my readfile and writefile to the subs that contain:ByRef Overlapped As System.Threading.NativeOverlapped) As SafeFileHandle, and it worked!

Comment: I did wonder about NativeOverlapped. However, unless you actually use overlapped IO, you should do what I said with IntPtr.Zero.